# How to create new entities in Jekyll + Markdown

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I have a bunch of Markdown files. In them, I want to be able to use custom bullets and other images; these are implemented as images (with alt-text, but they're a lot prettier as images). The Markdown to create one of those images looks like this:

```
*![✨](https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/svg/2728.svg)*
```

(Yes, that's rendered inside `<em>` `</em>` - that's to simplify the CSS, since I can't put a class on the img tag easily.)

Is there a way to tell the parser that the single character `✨` should be rendered as the entire `<img>` tag?

The site is hosted on GitHub Pages, so answers need to restrict themselves to GitHub Flavored Markdown. If it can't easily be done, I could make a pre-commit hook or something and run a local parser, but it would be far easier to have it work automatically.

Comment: What do you mean with "rendered as the entire tag"?

Comment: I want my .md file to have a single character, and the final HTML to have an <img> tag in it. If that requires an intermediate block of Markdown, that's fine, just as long as it's automatic.

Comment: Just realized that my tag names were getting removed from the message, which made it harder to read. I've backticked them so you should now see that I meant "rendered as the entire <img> tag".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the emojis in *includes* and then reference them from your posts. That is compatible with Github Pages as it doesn't require plugins.

In your post put:

```
{% include emoji.html %}
```

That will load the contents of `_includes/emoji.html`:

```
<a href="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/svg/2728.svg">✨</a>
```

You can pass parameters to it to load different images depending on the image you want to load, e.g.: `{% include emoji.html image="stars" %}`

Another option is to create [custom liquid tags](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags) that load them.

Comment: Still massively verbose for what it does :( I think a preprocessor is better than this.

Comment: @rosuav agree, but that won't work on Github pages without some CI though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking of a git pre-commit hook, so it actually happens prior to the push. I think I'm staring at a choice between three or so bad options and picking the least clunky.

Comment: I've ended up going for a quite different approach; basically, my conclusion is that this isn't possible the way I wanted to do it.

Comment: @rosuav what approach did you end up using?

Comment: Styling the list differently and using the image in `li::before` instead of actually having the character in the source at all. Means I need 2-3 different blocks in the CSS file instead of doing it all with one generic "character => image" transformation, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

> ...since I can't put a class on the img tag easily.

You can if you use kramdown - it has a [feature](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes), which allows assigning attributes to the block level elements. For example:

```
![img]({{ 'img.png' | relative_url }}){: .center }
```

will become

```
<img src="...img.png" alt="img" class="center">
```

Comment: Cool, I can look into that for other reasons. Doesn't solve the main problem though.